# Returning complex object with PowerShell functions?

Tags: powershell

Most of out of the box PowerShell commands are returning "complex" objects.

for example, `Get-Process` returns an array of `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

All of the function I've ever wrote was returning either a simple type, or an existing kind of object.

If I want to return a home made objects, what are guidelines ?

For example, imagine I have an object with these attributes: `Name`, `Age`. In C# I would have wrote

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public uint Age { get; set; }
}
```

What are my options for returning such object from a PowerShell function ?

1. As my goal is to create PowerShell module, should I move to a c# module instead of a ps1 file ?
2. should I compile such objects in a custom DLL and reference it in my module using `LoadWithPartialName` ?
3. Should I put my class in a powershell string, then dynamically compile it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use this syntax:

```
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
   Name = 'Bob'
   Age = 32
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few options for creating your own object with custom properties. It is also possible to extend existing objects with additional properties. The most explicit method is to use the Add-Member cmdlet:

```
$test = New-Object PSCustomObject
Add-Member -InputObject $test -Name Name -Value 'Bob' -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $test -Name Age -Value 32 -MemberType NoteProperty
```

You can also use the fact that objects can be extended combined with the fact that Select-Object can implicitly add properties to objects in the pipeline:

```
$test = '' | Select @{n='Name'; e={'Bob'}}, @{n='Age'; e={32}}
```

Personally I prefer the first method since it is more explicit and less hand waving magic, but at the end of the day it's a scripting language so whatever works is the right way to do it.